# Mapbox Inflate View on Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, mapbox

I am having issues inflating a Mapbox MapView on an Android Fragment. When I use the same code on an Activity (other than standard differences between an Activity and a Fragment), I can get the MapView to load correctly, but not on the Fragment.

Mapbox also has a MapFragment class [here](https://github.com/mapbox/MapboxFragment), but I am unsure how to use this properly in a Fragment (the example is still in an Activity); with the Google Maps API I am able to use a MapView on a Fragment without a problem.

The below logcat line of:

```
at com.example.exampleapp.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:133)
```

is referring to the Java line:

```
fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
```

Here is the relevant code for this issue along with the log:

fragment_map.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:mapbox="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        mapbox:access_token="@string/access_token"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/map_card"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp">
        <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/mini_map"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            mapbox:access_token="@string/access_token"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

FragmentMap.java:

```
public class FragmentMap extends Fragment {
    private MapView mv, miniMap;
        View fragmentLayout;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);

    mv = (MapView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    miniMap = (MapView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.mini_map);
    miniMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    return fragmentLayout;
}


@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mv.onStart();
    miniMap.onStart();
}
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    mv.onStop();
    miniMap.onStop();
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mv.onDestroy();
    miniMap.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mv.onResume();
    miniMap.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mv.onPause();
    miniMap.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onLowMemory() {
    super.onLowMemory();
    mv.onLowMemory();
    miniMap.onLowMemory();
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    mv.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    miniMap.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

logcat:

```
01-07 08:07:00.548 710-710/com.example.exampleapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.exampleapp, PID: 710
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #13: Error inflating class com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:633)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at com.example.exampleapp.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:133)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1778)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:871)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:841)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1115)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$1.onClick(TabLayout.java:665)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at com.example.exampleapp.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:133)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1778)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:871)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:841)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1115)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$1.onClick(TabLayout.java:665)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.exampleapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmapbox-gl.so"
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.NativeMapView.<clinit>(NativeMapView.java:42)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:680)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView.<init>(MapView.java:621)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:607)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:743)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
at com.example.exampleapp.FragmentMap.onCreateView(FragmentMap.java:133)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:552)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItemInternal(ViewPager.java:514)
at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setCurrentItem(ViewPager.java:495)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$ViewPagerOnTabSelectedListener.onTabSelected(TabLayout.java:1778)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:871)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout.selectTab(TabLayout.java:841)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$Tab.select(TabLayout.java:1115)
at android.support.design.widget.TabLayout$1.onClick(TabLayout.java:665)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

app gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exampleapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:r1.5.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.3.0'
    compile('com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:2.3.0@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    compile files('libs/commons-lang3-3.3.2.jar')
}
```

Project Structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you attach screenshot with your project folder structure? Problem lies probably in wrongly placed `libmapbox-gl.so`.

Comment: Just added app gradle

Comment: Yea, you're probably right, but I've worked with Mapbox before without a problem and haven't had to deal with that at all.  In fact, I can get a Mapbox view to work on this app in an Activity without changing anything else.

Comment: I'll get the screenshot up asap

Comment: Check if you have `libmapbox-gl.so` in `android/java/lib/src/main/jniLibs/armeabi-v7a/` or `android/java/lib/src/main/libs/armeabi-v7a/` or `android/java/lib/src/main/jni/armeabi-v7a/` - with one of these locations should work (not sure which one)

Comment: This may sound stupid, but I don't even see an "android/java/lib" structure.  My "src" is under "app" for all my projects.

Comment: I meant this level - http://i.imgur.com/iJDUZXR.png ; I don't know logic of this component, so my answers are result of seeing this error `nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]] couldn't find "libmapbox-gl.so"` in your log

Comment: I'm not seeing that view in any of the Project view options.  What are you selecting?  This is in Android Studio.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100093/discussion-between-damian-kozlak-and-tangojlabs).

Comment: I just added the structure screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the help Damian!

Answer (score 3):

You are telling about inflation but look at stack trace:

> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError:
>   dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file
>   "/data/app/com.example.exampleapp-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib,
>   /system/lib]]] **couldn't find "libmapbox-gl.so"** at
>   java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:366) at
>   java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:988) at
>   com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.NativeMapView.(NativeMapView.java:42)
>   at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView.initialize(MapView.java:680) at
>   com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.views.MapView.(MapView.java:621)

BTW:

first

u need to decide if u inflate view every time {local variable) or u reuse it (global one)

example:

```
if(_view==null) 
   _view = inflater.inflate(..);
return _view;
```

second:

do not call activities or fragment methods like onCreate onPause manually (those used by os to maintain life cycle)

third:

if u use viewpager  and nested fragments u need  create  adapter with child fragment manager

more &  more:

keep in mind that to set some data and properties in child fragment  viewpager fragment need to laid out

> *"First: I am inflating it every time, which is usually not a problem (my tabs work with any other fragment I have created, including Google Maps, just not Mapbox) Second: Yes, you do call activity lifecycle methods manually. You have to use onCreate to inflate a view. Third: I have an adapter, I just did not include it here. That is not the issue, my tabs work fine with any other fragment I have created. Lastly: I'm not sure what you're saying, but my fragments work fine in my other tabs.*
>
> *Please focus on the problem at hand... putting a Mapbox view in a fragment, > regardless of where that fragment is (tab pageviewer or not).. – TangoJLabs"*

```
/**
 * Called to do initial creation of a fragment.  This is called after
 * {@link #onAttach(Activity)} and before
 * {@link #onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)}.
 *
 * <p>Note that this can be called while the fragment's activity is
 * still in the process of being created.  As such, you can not rely
 * on things like the activity's content view hierarchy being initialized
 * at this point.  If you want to do work once the activity itself is
 * created, see {@link #onActivityCreated(Bundle)}.
 *
 * @param savedInstanceState If the fragment is being re-created from
 * a previous saved state, this is the state.
 */
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mCalled = true;
}
```

move this from onCreate of fragment to onViewCreated(View,Bundle)

```
mv = (MapView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

miniMap = (MapView) fragmentLayout.findViewById(R.id.mini_map);
miniMap.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


/**
 * Called immediately after {@link #onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)}
 * has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view.
 * This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once
 * they know their view hierarchy has been completely created.  The fragment's
 * view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.
 * @param view The View returned by {@link #onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)}.
 * @param savedInstanceState If non-null, this fragment is being re-constructed
 * from a previous saved state as given here.
 */
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
```

last word:  gradle files

i dont know if your file content contains both gradle files or only app file but those lines shouldnt be in app gradle file - those are top level gradle :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
}
```

and u should consider to move to newest android app plugin  - but i see you are using gms services - so u top gradle file is containing other plugin and those above is omitted

> *I'm having trouble following the logic of your edits. I don't have an onCreate from which I can move anything*

```
/** inflate fragment  - this will create view */
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container, false);
}

/** after view is created - set map view */
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    if(view!=null) {
       MapView mv = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.mapview);
       mv.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

btw i have more concerns on rest of lifecycle methods - fragment could or not  retain state so simple putting activity lifecycle methods in fragment method could produce more problems :)

i don't use & know the source implementation of MapView so i cant tell u how to implement this but i can give u a hint to check if fragment is attached to activity before u call any mapview method

> @ceph3us -1 everything mentioned in this is wrong, and your grammar
>   can be improved. I don't have an answer to this, I am here with the
>   same question. 1st root view should not be a field, it should be
>   inflated on each call to onCreateView, 2nd those are proper calls, 3rd
>   and the rest are off topic and not helpful to the subject. – HaydenKai

@HaydenKai

1. first of all pleas specify the **SOURCES** for you deliberations
2. why u want to recreate view ? purpose ? to waste resources (like your time to code and user CPU and MEM)? - there where u can afford it or need a fresh one then its ok but in other cases *REUSE* !!!
3. the view does not need to be inflated at all, it can be normally created eg by return new LinearLayout(Context) or FrameLayout or any other complex view - this is a developer choice to use xml or java - i prefer not to use xml - i like pure JAVA :)
4. so at the very end i can say your -1 is empty one for me her

[image]

Comment: First:  I am inflating it every time, which is usually not a problem (my tabs work with any other fragment I have created, including Google Maps, just not Mapbox)

Second:  Yes, you do call activity lifecycle methods manually.  You have to use onCreate to inflate a view.

Third:  I have an adapter, I just did not include it here.  That is not the issue, my tabs work fine with any other fragment I have created.

Lastly:  I'm not sure what you're saying, but my fragments work fine in my other tabs.

Comment: Please focus on the problem at hand... putting a Mapbox view in a fragment, regardless of where that fragment is (tab pageviewer or not)...

Comment: I'm having trouble following the logic of your edits.  I don't have an onCreate from which I can move anything.

Comment: @HaydenKai was nice to meat you - btw you deserved special edit :)

Answer (score 1):

This library looks in heavy development status and might have some problems, which are mentioned on GitHub, especially when you run version 2.2.0.

Try change version to newest stable:

```
compile 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:3.0.0'
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Mapbox 3.0.0 did not solve this particular bug, but Damian is right, the Mapbox Android SDK is obviously under heavy development.  Hopefully Mapbox will provide documentation for use in a Fragment in the near future.

Comment: I ran into the same issue.

Are you saying that a Mapbox MapView cannot be used into a fragment ? That would be a real shame.

Comment: @jmc34 In comments under question exist link to chat. You can read my discussion with Tango.

Comment: I have managed to use a Mapbox 3.2 view in a Fragment, but as soon as a ViewPager is introduced I get a similar inflation error but without the "could not find" / unsatsfiedLinkError. Canview my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35557857/mapbox-inflate-mapview-on-fragment-with-viewpager-and-fragmentstatepageradapter